# Cannot read property 'getContext' of null with a closure

Tags: jquery, canvas, closures

Usually when rendering a canvas you wrap the code in

```
$(function() { ....});
```

However, the code I am using has a closure on the outside so it is formatted like..

```
(function () {...})();
```

I cannot fix the canvas getContext error with the $. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us some more code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not because you use closure or you need to use ready handler.

But the problem is when you use jQuery the method and try to combine the  getContext method of core javascript would throw an error indicating undefined function. To  fix this you need to do like this:

```
var $canvas = $('#jCanvas'); //From jQuery object
$canvas[0] //To JavaScript ::  [0] is first matched element
  .getContext('2d');
```

Now, this way the getContext is used over javascript element and works fine.

---

But for simplicity I wouldn't wrap them in jQuery but just use the JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```